# Не могу удалить со страницы элемент с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть на странице выпадающий список, при выборе нужного пункта, список скрывается и элемент становится `display:block`.
Не могу с помощью jQuery удалить этот элемент.

```js
$('.li_dropd').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('liprod');
  $('.active').appendTo('.w415_h50');
  $('.active').toggleClass('active');
  $('.but_none1').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.li_dropd2').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active2');
  $(this).addClass('liprod');
  $('.active2').appendTo('.w415_h501');
  $('.active2').removeClass('active2');
  $('.but_none2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group drpopdown_one_protein2_hide1">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle-1 but_none1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="select_regiastr">
           Выберите вкус 1-го протеинового коктейля <span class="arrow_dropdown arrow_dropdown-1"> <img src="img/arrow_dropdown.png" alt=""></span>
          </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu drpopdown_one_protein">
    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/bank_proteins_dropdown.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом малины</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_banana.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом банана</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_strawberries.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом клубники</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_vanilla.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом ванили</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_chokolad.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом шоколада</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_plombir.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом пломбира</p>
    </li>

    <li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_moaccino.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span>
      <p class="taste">со вкусом мокачино</p>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="w415_h50 dis_flex_jc_al">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.but_none1').css('display', 'none');
$('.but_none1').remove();
```