# Не могу удалить нужный мне элемент через jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не получается удалить элемент с помощью jQuery.
Имеется такой jQuery код, который при клике добавляет классы и вставляет новосозданный элемент в нужный мне блок.

```
$('.li_dropd').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('liprod');
    $('.active').appendTo('.w415_h50') ;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.but_none1').css('display','none');
});
```

Имеется html код, в котором есть список из которого мы выбираем нужный нам пункт, при клике на данный пункт , сам список скрывается, и пункт списка переносится внутрь тега с классом "w415_h50".

```
<div class="btn-group drpopdown_one_protein2_hide1">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle-1 but_none1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="select_regiastr">Выберите вкус 1-го протеинового коктейля <span class="arrow_dropdown arrow_dropdown-1"> <img src="img/arrow_dropdown.png" alt=""></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu drpopdown_one_protein">
<li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/bank_proteins_dropdown.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span><p class="taste">со вкусом малины</p></li>
<li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_banana.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span><p class="taste">со вкусом банана</p></li>
<li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_strawberries.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span><p class="taste">со вкусом клубники</p></li>
<li class="li_dropd"><img src="img/taste_vanilla.png" alt="">Протеиновый коктейль <span>«Quest»</span><p class="taste">со вкусом ванили</p></li>
</ul>
<div class="w415_h50 dis_flex_jc_al">
// сюда при выборе вставляется нужный нам пункт
</div>
</div>
```

Не получается при клике на данный новосозданный элемент удалить его и вернуть список. li::after тут иконка крестика, что бы удалить блок.
Написал такой код, но он не срабатывает

```
$('.w415_h50 li::after').click(function () {
    $('w415_h50 li').remove();
    $('.but_none1').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: $('w415_h50 li').remove(); вы тут точку не пропустили случайно? перед именем класса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу удалить со страницы элемент с помощью jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788521/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery)

Comment: На кой плодить один и тот же вопрос, тем более если на него ответили

Comment: в доме псевдоэлементов не существует

Comment: Не является дубликатом, @kizoso правильно описала проблему.

Comment: А вы указали в `$('w415_h50 li').remove();` это id или class. Попробуйте: `$('.w415_h50 li').remove();`